# Modify or generate Android resources.arsc and compiled manifest

Tags: java, android, resources, apk

I would like to create an app that allows the user to generate an APK based on some static code i provide. Java code won't change, i will just have to modify the AndroidManifest.xml and the resources (either modifying the resources.arsc or creating a new one from scratch since i have the R.java available).

The number and name of resources will not change, just the content of strings and the drawables content is modified (means R.java doesnt need to be generated again)

So, assuming i can pre compile everything and put it into the app, is there any way to do this without having a java compiler on the device? I can put aapt and aidl binaries into the APK. Singing at the end wouldnt be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this app : [ThemeDIY](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.darkion.theme.maker&hl=en), you can also check the demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=299&v=w9atVhnYbx0).

This app allows users to choose various assets(drawable resources, ttf files, etc.) for customizing their themes and then, compile and assembles together to get apk file for them.

It uses kellinwood's [ZipSigner](https://code.google.com/archive/p/zip-signer/) library for signing the apk and [lingala Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) for creating zip files.

I think its same as you want to do, choosing/modifying resources(keeping names of resources same) and generate apk.

So, the solution for you would be to have static contents(i.e. contents of apk like its manifest file, jar file, dex file, res folder, etc) ready in a folder, create a copy as a temp folder, modify resources contents (and not names) as per user needs, then finally create zip of this temp folder and sign it to have the desired .apk file (no need for java complier then).

Hope it helps !

---

**Update**

Okay, after discussing in comments, I figured out following (in detail whole process mentioned below) :

We need to create a apk from our app (after modification of resources). So, things required for apk generation :

- classes.dex file
- manifest.xml file
- res folder
- android.jar file (you can find it in a location like /platforms/android-/android.jar)

Tools required :

- aapt
- dx
- jarsigner
- zipalign

---

Below all steps are done in android during app's runtime, except for the first step.

---

First we need is classes.dex file, which can be generated :

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex SomeJar1.jar SomeJar2.jar ..
```

where these jars are your compiled classes (This step can be done in windows/linux, as these are static contents).

---

Now, put required things for our apk generation in android app cache directory's temp folder at runtime :

```
getApplictionContext().getCacheDir() + "/tmp/"
```

Copy classes.dex, AndroidManifest.xml and res/ folder to above folder.

(You might want to keep classes.dex, AndroidManifest.xml and res folder in your application's raw folder initially and then use FileInputStream class to copy it (like we do it in java) into above tmp folder at runtime.)

---

Now, do modification of res folder in this cache's tmp directory, as per needed.

---

After modification, its time to package initial apk, we need to run following command from our android app :

```
aapt package -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res/ -I android.jar -F MyProject.apk.unaligned
```

And so, code now becomes for android :

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.append("aapt package -f -M");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/tmp/AndroidManifest.xml -S ");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/tmp/res -I ");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/tmp/android.jar -F ");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/apk/MyProject.apk.unaligned");
sb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
```

---

So, now we have initial apk with resources.arsc and encrypted manifest inside this apk. But we need to add classes.dex file, so we run the following command :

```
aapt add -f MyProject.apk.unaligned classes.dex
```

From android we write :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("aapt add -f");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/apk/MyProject.apk.unaligned ");
sb.append(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
sb.append("/tmp/classes.dex");
sb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());
```

---

Sign the package, use the command :

```
jarsigner -storepass <keystore password> -keystore <keystore filename> MyProject.apk.unaligned <key name>
```

(Can be converted to android code, similarly as above)

---

Finally, align it, using command :

```
zipalign 4 MyProject.apk.unaligned MyProject.apk
```

(Again, this can be converted to android code, same as above)

---

So, now we have android apk completely ready, either install it or copy it to sd card as you may like.

All code above has been tested and is working fine !

Hope now this helps !

Comment: Thanks, i know its possible problem is that i dont know how to create a resources.arsc file and how to encrypt the manifest, thats the tricky thing, that cannot be done with zipsigner

Comment: I think you can reverse engineer it, build apk for your static contents once, now, simply change the generated apk file extension to zip file and extract it, you will have resources.arsc and encrypted manifest file. Now, put them in your static contents folder and do as suggested. Resources.arsc is static for you since, since resource names do not change. I know that aapt generates R.java and resources.arsc, and I am searching for a direct way, but reverse engineering way should also do !

Comment: Resources.arsc is not static, i need to change that and there is no need to reverse engineer anything here, i already have everything, so i need to be able to generate the resource file and manifest file

Comment: I got your point, but I don't think so it will be straight forward then. Check out how android does it here : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4ad6291b08c8ff0ab2d8efadd4bd6aacd59dd904/tools/aapt/Resource.cpp#L1633

Comment: And this is for manifest : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4ad6291b08c8ff0ab2d8efadd4bd6aacd59dd904/tools/aapt/Resource.cpp#L1709

Comment: Glad to help :)